# How to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1 with multiple hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I have only used Linux Mint before and installation was very straightforward and automatic. I just got a new laptop with a 128gb SSD and 1tb HDD. I have two questions:

1. I don't need Ubuntu on the SSD but I still want Grub to ask me which OS to boot. Can I install Ubuntu on the HDD and still get this feature, even though it's not technically "alongside" the Windows boot manager?
2. During installing, I choose "Something else" when prompted for where to install. This partition menu makes no sense to me and I don't know if I should, or how to, create a new partition from here for Ubuntu. Here is a screenshot of the partial list (and this is the factory state of the laptop):

[image: partition editor]

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a standard UEFI install. You only show 214MB used on sda1? Or is that an Intel SRT or cache which installer may not see correctly? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system Just be sure to use Something Else and install grub to sdb. It does try to default to an efi partition on sda, but you do not show one.

Comment: @mikewhatever I followed that article by my partition list was much more complicated, and following their steps resulted in running out of space during installation.

Comment: @oldfred Thank you, these are good resources, I'm currently partitioning for EXT4 space for the install and another for Linux swap space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to Boot Ubuntu from another hard drive where GRUB still asks you which OS to run.
Create a new partition on your desired drive from New Partition Table, format it to ext4, Mount it to '/' directory.
Install Ubuntu then before restart open the terminal and run

sudo update-grub